# Why won't sql server express 2008 service restart after I enable TCP/IP Protocol?

Tags: sql-server-2008, tcpip

Whenever I enable TCP/IP connections on my SQL Server Express 2008 database server running on Windows XP SP3, I cannot restart the service, it simply states "The request failed or did respond in a timely fashion". Any suggestions of what I may have configured incorrectly?

[update]
Here is the applicable part of the Error Log:

```
MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS Server failed to list on 'any'  3060. Error: 0x2747. To proceed, notify you system administrator.

MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x2747, status code 0xa. Reason: Unable to initialize the TCP/IP listener. An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x2747, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. 
An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS Could not start the network library  because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.

MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS SQL Server could not spawn FRunCM thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems.
```

Comment: Check the Event Viewer logs for errors.

Comment: What's in the SQL ERRORLOG file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that rebooting the PC was enough to clear this error.

Comment: There is any solution without reboot! If its server the reboot was not good solution